# Trying to assign value from dict to fabric env setting

Tags: python, fabric

I am writing my first environment-specific fabfile. Essentially, I have created a env settings file for each environment that contains a json string with the user, password and host. then I have a task for each environment that gets called prior to the actual deploy function. Something like this:

fab dev deployApp

The dev task (in this case) calls a function I wrote that parses the related settings file and attempts to set the env settings to the parsed values.

```
def set_env(env):
    json_data = open(env + '_settings.env', 'r')
    env_data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    env.user = env_data['user']
    env.password = env_data['password']
```

However, when I call this function I receive the following error that I cannot seem to decipher:

```
env.user = "" + env_data['user']
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I tested that the file is being read by printing the values and they are indeed correct. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the accessing of the dict value but cannot seem to find the right search combination to give me an answer that works.

Comment: The problem isn't in accessing the dictionary values, it's in `env.user`. `env` is clearly a string, since you did `env + '_settings.env'`. So why are you trying to set `env.user`?

Comment: Oh wow. I'm an idiot. Env is a reserved collection in fabric and I tried to re-use that for my param name. Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me. Argh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the parameter name, since it's replacing your global variable `env`. Something like:

```
def set_env(env_str):
    json_data = open(env_str + '_settings.env', 'r')
    env_data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    env.user = env_data['user']
    env.password = env_data['password']
```